# Clearing NSTextfield bound to a nsmutablestring

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextfield, nsmutablestring

I have a text field bound to a nsmutableablestring.  In the action item for a button I want to clear this string but it's throwing an exception saying it's immutable.

Member variable is

```
NSMutableString* firstName;
```

Property for binding to the text field is declared in .h

```
@property (copy) NSMutableString* firstName;
```

In the action for the button the following line throws an exception

```
[firstName setString:@""];
```

I don't have any trouble reading the value in firstName to access what is in the text field so the binding appears to be working.

Here is the stack trace

```
Attempt to mutate immutable object with setString:
2012-01-22 14:48:58.084 testproj[2509:707] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff88233286 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff857bdd5e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff882330ba +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff88233044 +[NSException raise:format:] + 116
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff882892dd mutateError + 93
    5   testproj                            0x00000001000035c4 -[AppController AddCustomer:] + 388
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff88222a1d -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 61
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8f319710 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 139
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8f319642 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 88
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8f31956d -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 137
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f318a30 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 2014
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f3988e0 -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 489
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f31763a -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 786
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f2e20e0 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 6306
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f27a68f -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 5593
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f210682 -[NSApplication run] + 555
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f48f80c NSApplicationMain + 867
```

Comment: Have you alloc'd and init'd  it

Comment: I cannot get this not to work :-). Although I have used lazy initiation for the firstname so all my calls are self.firstName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you relying on the synthesized setter?  `copy` returns an immutable copy so you need to define your own setter.  See http://vgable.com/blog/2009/03/17/mutable-property-and-copy-gotcha/ for more details